# Pandas replace not working as expected on multiple column subset

Tags: python, pandas

There seems to be an issue with pandas replace() option when doing replacement on only a few columns:

```
# Example dataframe:
pd.DataFrame(data={"x":[1,2,3,4,5], "y":[2,4,1,2,4], "z":["no", "yes", "no", "no", "no"], "t":["a", "b", "c", "d", "d"]})

# Try to replace the 2s inplace:
a.loc[:, ["x", "y"]].replace(2,-9999, inplace=True)
```

a is still:

```
Out[32]: 
x  y    z  t
0  1  2   no  a
1  2  4  yes  b
2  3  1   no  c
3  4  2   no  d
4  5  4   no  d
```

Note that I do not get a settingWithCopy warning - also, I am using .loc as recommended. Since I use inplace=True, I would have expected the dataframe to change. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug to report on github?

I am using pandas version 0.23.0.

Comment: `a.loc[:, ["x", "y"]]` uses `.loc.__getitem__`. When using `__getitem__`, the returned object might be a copy. Here, `a.loc[:, ["x", "y"]]` returns a copy and that copied structured is in fact modified inplace but since you didn't assign it to anything you cannot see the change. The original df remains unchanged as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannnot use `inplace=True`, because subset returns a Series which may have its data as a view. Modifying it in place doesn't ALWAYS propogate it back to the parent object. That's why this warning is there (or raise if you set the option). You should never do this, nor is their ever a reason to do so.

```
a.loc[:, ["x", "y"]] = a.loc[:, ["x", "y"]].replace(2,-9999)
print (a)
      x     y    z  t
0     1 -9999   no  a
1 -9999     4  yes  b
2     3     1   no  c
3     4 -9999   no  d
4     5     4   no  d
```

Another solution is [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), be default working `inplace`:

```
a.update(a.loc[:, ["x", "y"]].replace(2,-9999))
print (a)
      x     y    z  t
0     1 -9999   no  a
1 -9999     4  yes  b
2     3     1   no  c
3     4 -9999   no  d
4     5     4   no  d
```

Comment: That was fast, and worked, thanks. Unfortunately, this means I'll have to type my indexing twice (right and left side), there is no way around this? My real indexing is unfortunately not as short as [:, ["x", "y"]] :-\

Comment: @Thomas Or you can save the indexing to a variable: `idx = pd.IndexSlice[:, ['x', 'y']]` and use it in loc: `a.loc[idx] = ...`

Comment: @jezrael: Great idea! I would not have thought of using update in this context, I only ever used it to replace NA values

Comment: @user2285236: I didn't even know about IndexSlice. This will be very helpful in the future. Really glad I asked this question.

Comment: `IndexSlice` is used obviously for select  complicated `MultiIndex` with `slice`, check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers). Here working nice `idx = ['x', 'y']`, but thank you for commenting.

Comment: I don't think you have any other option if you want to save both the row and the column indexers to the same variable?

Comment: @user2285236 - just test it `idx = pd.IndexSlice[[1,2], ['x', 'y']]
a.loc[idx] = 4`